# Executing Linux Command in Scala-Shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sqoop, spark-shell, scala-shell

I'm working on a project where I'm needing to execute some linux commands (sqoop command) in my Scala application. See sample command I tried executing with MySql on my VM.

```
import sys.process._ 

"sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --query 'select * from categories'".!
```

I got the following error:

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
20/06/24 15:25:27 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0
20/06/24 15:25:27 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. 
Consider using -P instead.
20/06/24 15:25:27 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for eval:
20/06/24 15:25:27 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: *
20/06/24 15:25:27 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: from
20/06/24 15:25:27 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: categories
```

I used this command as well and I got same error message:

```
"sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --query 'select * from categories'".!<
```

Can someone help me figure out what's cause of the error. I've tried using single quote and double quotes, all to no avail. I searched all over SO but I could not get any solution. That's why I'm posting here.
NOTE: Same command successfully executed in pyspark as seen below:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys

>>> query = "sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db --username root --password 
cloudera --query 'select * from categories'" 
>>> os.system(query)
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
20/06/24 15:28:56 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0
20/06/24 15:28:56 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. 
Consider using -P instead.
20/06/24 15:28:58 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
----------------------------------------------------
| category_id | category_department_id | category_name        | 
----------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 2           | Football             | 
| 2           | 2           | Soccer               | 
| 3           | 2           | Baseball & Softball  | 
| 4           | 2           | Basketball           | 
| 5           | 2           | Lacrosse             | 
| 6           | 2           | Tennis & Racquet     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `sqoop` doesn't recognize `*`, `from`, and `categories` as individual arguments. The reason it works when invoked from the command line is that the shell interprets the quote marks and presents them as a single `select * from categories` argument. In other words, the shell does some pre-processing before handing everything off to the `sqoop` program.

The `.!` method (i.e. the Scala `ProcessBuilder`) launches processes directly, which means that the command elements are not passed to a shell for pre-processing. There are two ways to get around this problem.

1. You can invoke the shell directly and pass the command-line to it as a single argument, or
2. you can do most of the obvious pre-processing yourself.

Here's an example of the 2nd option.

```
Seq("sqoop"
   ,"eval"
   ,"--connect"
   ,"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db"
   ,"--username"
   ,"root"
   ,"--password"
   ,"cloudera"
   ,"--query"
   ,"select * from categories").!
```

As you can see, all the individual arguments are presented as individual arguments, including the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Please would you  be  elaborate a little more. I've never used the ProcessBuilder, so I really didnt understand the answer you provided. I copied what you wrote and executed, yet it failed. I searched to understand ProcessBuilder in order to be able to understand your answer, I didn't get any concrete doc to help me.  I will really appreciate your time..

Comment: Oh my Goodness, it worked. You are indeed a life saver. You just saved me from a weeklong headache. I'm truly grateful.  God bless you..